FCM Gem, setting icon
I have been trying to set an icon for the payload of the FCM ruby gem. All the resources say to put the icon in your androids res/drawable, but this is a ruby gem - so I am unsure how to set it up. Any ideas on how to get this to work? Does it have to be in the android app?
